# Маршрут не виден целиком (ymaps)

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Есть карта с автомобильным маршрутом из точки А в точку Х и кнопкой. При активации кнопки маршрут меняется на пешеходный из точки В в точку Х, а при деактивации кнопки - маршрут возвращается в исходное состоянии.

Проблема в том, что при активации кнопки, часть пешеходного маршрута становится не видна. Как сделать так чтобы при изменении маршрута, изменялись границы карты и маршрут умещался целиком?

Сам скрипт:

```
ymaps.ready(function () {
// Задаём точки мультимаршрута.
var pointA = [57.357517, 37.594334], // Стадион
    pointB = [57.352960, 37.589776], // Вокзал
    pointX = "Кашин, улица Вонжинская, 2",
    /**
     * Создаем мультимаршрут.
     * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/multiRouter.MultiRoute.xml
     */
    multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
        referencePoints: [
            pointA,
            pointX
        ],
        params: {
            //Тип маршрутизации - автомобильная маршрутизация.
            routingMode: 'auto'
        }
    }, {
        // Позволяет скрыть иконки путевых точек маршрута.
        wayPointVisible:false,

        // Автоматически устанавливать границы карты так, чтобы маршрут был виден целиком.
        boundsAutoApply: true
    });

// Создаем кнопку.
var changePointsButton = new ymaps.control.Button({
    data: {content: "Как пройти"},
    options: {selectOnClick: true}
});

// Объявляем обработчики для кнопки.
changePointsButton.events.add('select', function () {
    //myMap.setBounds(multiRoute.getBounds(), {checkZoomRange:true});
    multiRoute.model.setReferencePoints([pointB, pointX]);
    multiRoute.model.setParams({routingMode: 'pedestrian'}, true);
    changePointsButton.data.set({content: 'Как проехать'});
});

changePointsButton.events.add('deselect', function () {     
    //myMap.setBounds(multiRoute.getBounds(), {checkZoomRange:true});
    multiRoute.model.setReferencePoints([pointA, pointX]);
    multiRoute.model.setParams({routingMode: 'auto'}, true);
    changePointsButton.data.set({content: 'Как пройти'});
});

// Создаем карту с добавленной на нее кнопкой.
var myMap = new ymaps.Map('YMapsID', {
    center: [57.358381, 37.613440],
    zoom: 12,
    controls: [changePointsButton]
}, {
    buttonMaxWidth: 300
});

// Отключаем масштабирование карты колесиком мыши
myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom'); 

// Добавляем мультимаршрут на карту.
myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);
});
```

[Так же собрал пример на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rx2h3ood/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Категорически не согласен ставить задержки там где они не нужны. У мультимаршрута есть вполне адекватное вашей задаче событие `boundschange`

```
//...
myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);
// обязательно назначаем обработчик после добавления маршрута на карту
multiRoute.events.add("boundschange", function() {
    myMap.setBounds(multiRoute.getBounds(), { checkZoomRange:true });
});
//...
```

Comment: да, так, конечно, лучше; я просто исправила код, который человек написал в своём примере на jsfiddle, чтобы он заработал :)

Comment: @Reni :) Я реально был удивлен такому решению

Comment: спасибо, товарищи, оба варианта отлично работают

Answer (score 0):

Вы правильно хотели использовать событие `requestsuccess`, но дело в том, что в момент получения ответа от сервера сама геометрия маршрута еще не успевает измениться, поэтому в `getBounds()` возвращается старое значение.

Попробуйте так:

```
multiRoute.model.events.add("requestsuccess", function() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    myMap.setBounds(multiRoute.getBounds(),{checkZoomRange:true});
  }, 100);
});
```

Comment: <сарказм>С таким подходом можно не ловить событие requestsuccess а поставить таймаут в секунду относительно нажатия кнопки, авось успеет запрос обработаться</сарказм>